# reduce function in JavaScript and the accumulator object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a query in relation to the reduce function.

The code is as follows:

```
const marks = [60, 55, 80, 89, 90, 98, 75, 72, 50, 30, 20, 42]
const grade_count = marks.reduce(groupByGrade, {})
function groupByGrade (acc, mark) {
  
  const {a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, f = 0} = acc;
  if (mark >= 90) {
    return {...acc, a: a + 1};
  }
  if (mark >= 80) {
    return {...acc, b: b + 1};
  }
  if (mark >= 70) {
    return {...acc, c: c + 1};
  }
  if (mark >= 60) {
    return {...acc, d: d + 1};
  }
  else {
    return {...acc, f: f + 1};
  }
}
 
console.log (marks)
console.log (grade_count)
console.log ('woo hoo')
```

My query is in relation to the following line where the accumulator is destructured for the first time:

```
const {a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, f = 0} = acc;
```

I wish to understand how come the  properties on the accumulator object not get reset to zero on every iteration of the `marks` array.

What am I missing here please?

Comment: They're _default_ values - if there's a non-default value, they're not used.

Comment: Compare `let {a=0}={};console.log(a)` and `let {a=0}={a:9}; console.log(a)`

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to understand how come the properties on the accumulator object not get reset to zero on every iteration of the marks array.

Because the `= 0` part of

```
const {a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, f = 0} = acc;
```

...is only used **if** the effective value of the property being destructured is `undefined` ("effective" = it's actually `undefined`, or the property's not there at all).

On subsequent calls to the reducer, `acc` has non-`undefined` values for those properties, so the default isn't used.

---

Just as a side note, you could do the destructuring in the parameter list:

```
function groupByGrade({a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, f = 0}, mark) {
    // ...
}
```

...although `a`, `b`, and the others wouldn't be constants anymore.

Comment: FWIW, I go into destructuring -- including how default values work -- in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 7 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.